# How to restart a gif animation on a new page?

Tags: javascript, animation, gif

I made a GIF animation running for a few seconds, and is **not** looped. When I put the gif on different pages, the animation does not restart because its cached... it just stays on the last frame. How can I make it restart when it is on a new page? I know of ways how to rename it or add "?" to it, but it will give me bandwidth issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this method will cause the browser to request the GIF from your server a second time, but this should force the GIF animation to restart on subsequent pages:

Your image:

```
<img id="animatedgif" src="picture.gif">
```

And at the bottom of the page, near the closing `BODY` and `HTML` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("animatedgif").src = "";
    document.getElementById("animatedgif").src = "picture.gif";
</script>
```